# How to update a state using useState hook in react?

Tags: python, sql, reactjs, flask, use-state

Im a beginner in react, and I was trying to experiment with the useState Hook. I have a react file where I am fetching data from the database in flask which looks like this

```
import React, {useState, useEffect,useContext } from 'react'
import { Context } from "../../store/appContext"

function Main() {
  
  const {store, actions} = useContext(Context)
  const [notes, updateNotes] = useState([])
  let arr =[];
  const Notes = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch('/main/', {
      method: "GET",
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':"Bearer " + store.token
      },
    });
    if(resp.status === 200) {
      const data = await resp.json();
      arr = data.data
      arr.forEach(note => {
        updateNotes(...notes, note);
      })
      console.log("Array data",arr)
      updateNotes(...notes, arr);
      console.log("state data",notes);     
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    actions.getTokenAfterRefresh();
    Notes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      HEy this is thee main page!!!
      <div>
        Welcome {store.user}!
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* {numNotes == 0 ?
          <div>
            Create a new note
          </div>
        :
          <div>
            Display notes
          </div> */}
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Main
```

The flask api looks like this:

```
from flask import (request, Blueprint, jsonify, g)

from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask_jwt_extended import get_jwt_identity

from PIM.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/main')

@bp.route('/',methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@jwt_required()
def mainPage():
  num=0;
  data =[];
  if request.method == 'GET':
    db = get_db()
    user = get_jwt_identity()
    if user is not None:
      userdata = db.execute('SELECT Info, Title from UserNotes INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = UserNotes.user WHERE Users.username = ?',[user]).fetchall()
      for row in userdata:
        data.append(list(row));
    return jsonify({'data': data}), 200
```

When I try to console log the data in arr variable it displays the data correctly. But when i log the data in the state it doesnt display any data.
Could you please help me solve this issue and also suggest why this is happening.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasuse setState in asynchronous. State `notes` only update new value when component re-render. You can check new value of `note` by using `console.log` before retrun`

```
console.log("state data",notes);    
return (...)
```

Comment: Ohk, so can I just change the state by using setState(arr)? I just tried and it is working

Comment: `setState` is the only way to update state